# Gmail content provider for message access

Tags: android, sms, gmail

Unlike Contacts, there is no currently public API available in the SDK to allow access to Gmail, SMS, and MMS.  The Gmail content provider does not appear to be publicly supported.  Does anyone have any information on using this content provider with Android 2.x, and/or the status of making Gmail, SMS and/or MMS access officially supported via the SDK or official documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some info on gmail content provider [How to get the number of unread gmail mails (on android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992635/how-to-get-the-number-of-unread-gmail-mails-on-android/3037279#3037279).