# Get the number of unread mails on an Android Device

Tags: android

Is there a way to ask the mail programms on an Android Device how many unread mails they have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was already answered on [How to get the number of unread gmail mails (on android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992635/how-to-get-the-number-of-unread-gmail-mails-on-android)