# Android ContentProvider Uri for Gmail Contacts

Tags: android

First of all apologies if this is a duplicate but I'm browsing via my mobile and am having problems searching.

I'm new to android development and would like to know how to access the gmail contacts rather than phone contacts, I've followed a couple of tutorials and can list the contacts that are stored on the phone but I am unable to find a ContentProvider Uri for GMail!

I am presuming that they are accessed in the same way that phone contacts are but using a different Uri but so far have been unable to find any information on this!

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

OneShot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that [How to get the number of unread gmail mails (on android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992635/how-to-get-the-number-of-unread-gmail-mails-on-android/3037279#3037279)?