# SecurityException: Permission Denial error

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I've just upgraded to the new version of gmail (v2.3.5) and I've got an app that queries the content provider to get details about the contacts that messages are received for......

With the latest version I'm getting the below error:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.gm.provider.MailProvider from ProcessRecord{40adef58 3576:com.rageconsulting.android.lightflow/10056} (pid=3576, uid=10056) requires com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_GMAIL or com.google.android.gm.permission.WRITE_GMAIL`

For gmail in my manifest I'm declaring the following:

```
<!--permissions for gmail-->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gmail.permission.READ_GMAIL"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_GMAIL"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gm.permission.WRITE_GMAIL"/>
```

So as far as I can tell I've got the permissions correct.

My gmail receiver looks like the following:

```
    <receiver android:name=".receiver.GmailReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED" android:priority="-10">
            </action>
            <data android:scheme="content" android:host="gmail-ls" android:pathPattern="/unread/.*">
            </data>
        </intent-filter>


        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED" android:priority="-10">
            </action>
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" android:scheme="content" android:host="gmail-ls" android:path="/unread/^i">
            </data>
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
```

Can anyone think of something that I may have missed out on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Google broke it for 'security reasons'. See this support thread:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?fid=1728955d050a12bd0004a9339272acdb&hl=en

You need to go back to the version before 2.3.5, which was 2.3.4.1

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't spotted that.