# cannot resolve the issue in count the unread emails in android

Tags: android, email

I am new to android development.I have a requirement to count the number of email sent and received. I have tried the code given in the link How to get the number of unread gmail mails (on android). I am running the code in android 2.2. But I am getting Security exception even though i have mention permission in manifest file.

**java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.gm.provider.MailProvider from ProcessRecord{40a44ec8 8832:com.android.gmailexample/10090} (pid=8832, uid=10090) requires com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_GMAIL or com.google.android.gm.permission.WRITE_GMAIL**

Below is my code

```
package com.android.gmailexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

 public class GmailCountActivity extends Activity {
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("Activity","Inside Oncrete");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    queryLabels();             
   }

public static final class LabelColumns {
    public static final String CANONICAL_NAME = "canonicalName";
    public static final String NAME = "name";
    public static final String NUM_CONVERSATIONS = "numConversations";
    public static final String NUM_UNREAD_CONVERSATIONS = "numUnreadConversations";
}

public void queryLabels(){
    Log.d("Activity","Inside query label");
    String account="email@company.com";
    Uri LABELS_URI = Uri.parse("content://gmail-ls/unread/");
    Uri ACCOUNT_URI = Uri.withAppendedPath(LABELS_URI, account);
    ContentResolver contentResolver= this.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ACCOUNT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    //iterate over all labels in the account
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int unreadColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(LabelColumns.NUM_UNREAD_CONVERSATIONS);
        int nameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(LabelColumns.NAME);
        do {
            String name = cursor.getString(nameColumn);
            String unread = cursor.getString(unreadColumn);//here's the value you need
            Log.d("Name", name);
            Log.d("Unread ", unread);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        Log.d("Unread count", String.valueOf(unreadColumn));
    }
 }
}
```

and manifest file is

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<activity
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".GmailCountActivity" >
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission   android:name="com.google.android.providers.gmail.permission.READ_GMAIL"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_GMAIL"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gm.permission.WRITE_GMAIL"/>
```

I am not able to locate the error. Any help will be appreciated.

Regards 
Pushpa

Comment: You cannot access gmail data. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871200/securityexception-permission-denial-error?