# "SecurityException: Permission Denial" when opening a calendar Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-calendar, android-securityexception

### Background

In order to go to the calendar at a specific time, we use this (based on [**this link**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intent-view)) :

```
@Nullable
public static Intent prepareIntentForCalendar(final Context context, final Date date) {
    Intent intent = null;
    final Uri.Builder builder = CalendarContract.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
    builder.appendPath("time");
    ContentUris.appendId(builder, date.getTime());
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(builder.build());
    final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    final ResolveInfo resolveActivity = pm.resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY
            | PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER);
    if (resolveActivity == null)
        return null;
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
    return intent;
}
```

Only if it's not null, we allow to use the Intent.

### The problem

Recently I've got a weird exception about this. It goes as such:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.calendar/time/-11518765200000 flg=0x58080000 cmp=com.google.android.gm/.browse.TrampolineActivity } from ProcessRecord{fb2ca43 25597:.../u0a127} (pid=25597, uid=10127) requires com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_GMAIL
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1945)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1891)
       at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityManager.java:4373)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1631)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4762)
       at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:68)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4702)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:751)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5123)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5091)
       at 
       ...
```

### What I've found

The docs don't say anything about permission requirement. In fact, it says the opposite, if all you use is an Intent:

> Your application doesn't need permissions to read and write calendar
>   data. It can instead use intents supported by Android's Calendar
>   application to hand off read and write operations to that application.
>   The following table lists the intents supported by the Calendar
>   Provider:

Searching the Internet, I didn't get even one good clue about what's going on.

Only thing I know is that it occurs on various devices and various Android versions, as reported on Crashlytics:

[image]

For now, I've also reported about this [**here**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79658834), because I believe this crash shouldn't occur.

### The questions

1. Why does it occur?
2. Will adding the permission in the manifest help?
3. What should I do to handle it? I can wrap with try-catch for now, but seeing that this error occurs means there is actually an app that can handle the Intent, yet it doesn't let me reach it...
4. Is there perhaps any good fallback?

Comment: Strange i'm not getting any exception using above code

Comment: @NileshRathod It is strange. I thought it should be safe, but apparently we got 222 crashes on 141 users in the past 3 months.

Comment: i have tested above code in `api 23` and `api 24` working fine in my device  really strange  that crash report

Comment: @NileshRathod Do you also use Crashlytics? Maybe it found a crash that the Play Store can't.

Comment: I'm not using `Crashlytics` and about this *`Maybe it found a crash that the Play Store can't`* may be but I'm not sure about it

Comment: I saw the above error is about something in gmail error. Try this if it can fix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871200/securityexception-permission-denial-error

Comment: @TamHuynh Try what exactly? The only answer is to go back versions. Version of what here? All I do is open an intent...