# Count the number of email sent and received in android

Tags: android, email

I am new to android development.I have a requirement to count the number of email sent and received. 
I have tried the code given in the link  [How to get the number of unread gmail mails (on android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992635/how-to-get-the-number-of-unread-gmail-mails-on-android). I am running the code in android 2.2. But I am getting Security exception even though i have mention permission in manifest file.

**java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.gm.provider.MailProvider from ProcessRecord{40a44ec8 8832:com.android.gmailexample/10090} (pid=8832, uid=10090) requires com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_GMAIL or com.google.android.gm.permission.WRITE_GMAIL**

Here is my code

```
package com.android.gmailexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class GmailCountActivity extends Activity {
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("Activity","Inside Oncrete");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        queryLabels();             
    }

    public static final class LabelColumns {
        public static final String CANONICAL_NAME = "canonicalName";
        public static final String NAME = "name";
        public static final String NUM_CONVERSATIONS = "numConversations";
        public static final String NUM_UNREAD_CONVERSATIONS = "numUnreadConversations";
    }

    public void queryLabels(){
        Log.d("Activity","Inside query label");
        String account="email@company.com";
        Uri LABELS_URI = Uri.parse("content://gmail-ls/unread/");
        Uri ACCOUNT_URI = Uri.withAppendedPath(LABELS_URI, account);
        ContentResolver contentResolver= this.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ACCOUNT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        //iterate over all labels in the account
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int unreadColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(LabelColumns.NUM_UNREAD_CONVERSATIONS);
            int nameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(LabelColumns.NAME);
            do {
                String name = cursor.getString(nameColumn);
                String unread = cursor.getString(unreadColumn);//here's the value you need
                Log.d("Name", name);
                Log.d("Unread ", unread);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            Log.d("Unread count", String.valueOf(unreadColumn));
        }
    }
   }
```

and my manifest file is

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".GmailCountActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gmail.permission.READ_GMAIL"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_GMAIL"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gm.permission.WRITE_GMAIL"/>
```

I am not able to locate the error. Any help will be appreciated.

Regards
Pushpa

Comment: This a good answer to your question i guess, [How to get the number of unread gmail mails (on android)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992635/how-to-get-the-number-of-unread-gmail-mails-on-android)

Comment: I'm not sure if this qualifies as an exact duplicate, but the question linked by @YaqubAhmad is _strongly_ related.

Comment: @ Yaqub Ahmad: Thanks. This link helps me to try different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately mail applications do not expose their content and data, and most of them are third part (closed source including gmail)
Thus, the thing you want is not approachable.

Answer (score 0):

We need ContentProvider to retrieve label data. We can use this to access up-to-date unread counts for specific accounts’ inboxes and labels.

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/04/gmail-public-labels-api.html