# Accessing Gmail content provider on Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, gmail

Following the [Android Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/android/) instructions, with hints from a [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992635/how-to-get-the-number-of-unread-gmail-mails-on-android/3037279#3037279), I tried to query the `content://com.google.android.gm/example@gmail.com/labels` URI on the emulator. The emulator can't find the `com.google.android.gm` provider, even though I'm running AVD with the Google APIs and even though I've went into the "Email" app and added my Gmail account.

How do I get the Gmail content provider on the emulator? I'm using API Level 16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I get the Gmail content provider on the emulator?

You don't. Gmail is a commercial application, distributed on devices, not the emulator. You are welcome to test this app on a device that has Gmail on it, though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, even though it's disappointing. Maybe I'm using the wrong approach; do you know of any way to ask Android, "Does the current user have any unread mail, whatever mail app they are using?"

Comment: @GarretWilson: There is no way to do that, sorry. Each app, at best, has its own API for that sort of thing.