# is it possible to access email using content provider in android

Tags: android, email, android-contentprovider

I'm writing an eMail app for accessing all types of mails(gmail,yahoo,hotmail etc)

Can I use the content provider to access the inbox data , instead of using third-party libraries like JavaMail.

If it is possible to **access mail using content provider** , please let me know how to it.

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

for gmail refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992635/how-to-get-the-number-of-unread-gmail-mails-on-android/3037279#3037279)

and for yahoo also you can access shared data via content provider `com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.mail.provider.MailProvider` [beware of this exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992635/how-to-get-the-number-of-unread-gmail-mails-on-android/3037279#3037279)