# Suggestions for inbox notifications in android?

Tags: android

I have few activities in android application with inbox Textview in the title.

I want to implement something like Inbox(Number of messages) to be shown on each screen

any one guide me what is the suitable way to show number of messages in each screen title bar?

one of my friend is calling webservice after 10 seconds again and again to achieve this functionality but I don't think it is a suitable way.

Comment: I hope this can help you : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779625/android-how-can-i-find-out-how-many-unread-email-the-user-has](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779625/android-how-can-i-find-out-how-many-unread-email-the-user-has)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/09/android-developer-tutorial-for_22.html